# How to call a method inside a jquery function from global scope?

Tags: jquery, methods, visibility

I am looking for a way to call a method inside a jquery function.

Example : in the above code, how can I call the `method()` method from global scope?

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.test = function() {

        var method = function() {
            alert('test succeeded!');
        };

    }

})( jQuery );
```

I tried with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).test.method(); // undefined

});
```

But this does not help.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kB7mc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is of local scope available inside the function `test` only, you cannot access it outside the scope. Instead you can do it this way. Also while calling it, remember to put method invocation `()` for `test` i.e `$(document).test().method();` instead of `$(document).test.method();`

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.test = function() {
         var method = function() {
            alert('test succeeded!');
        };

         return {method:method};
    }

})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).test().method(); // undefined
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpuBg/)

Using Jquery Plugin pattern.

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {

        method : function () {
            alert('test succeeded!');
            return this; //return element for chaining
        },
         method2 : function () {
            alert('test2 succeeded!');
             return this;
        }
    };

    $.fn.test = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).test('method'); 
    $(document).test('method2'); 

});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDrUy/)**

Comment: hmm, was guessing of a visibility/scope matter, but I actually don't want to return other stuffs than `this` at the end of my jquery plugin to match with good practices. Do you think there is another way to achieve this? Do you think I need to redesign my plugin? I have event listeners that need to use a method defined in the plugin.

Comment: @AlainTiemblo in that case yuo may follow jquery plugin pattern... By passing in the method name in the options argument. and return the element itself for chaining.

Comment: Here you go the url for this http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/

Comment: That was really simple, but just didn't knew about it. Thanks.