# how to extend $.fn with new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the the following jquery-function:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.formCheck = function(options) {
        var form = this;  var errorList = [];
        var settings = {
             errorClass: "error",
             focusInvalid: true,
             errorContainer: $([])
        }

        // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
        if(options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }

         var fc = {
              messages: {
                required: "Dieses Feld ist ein Pflichtfeld.",
                remote: "Please fix this field.",
                email: "Geben Sie bitte eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein.",
             }
          }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Now I would like to extend them with the following code:

```
(function($) {
    $.extend(formCheck.fc.messages, {
          required: "This field is required.",
          remote: "Please fix this field.",
          email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    });
}(jQuery));
```

I get the message ReferenceError: formCheck is not defined.

Whats wrong?

I made a new jsfiddle:[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAfF2/4/)

Comment: You can't access `fc` from outside of there.  It only exists inside the anonymous function.  You should pass your options to the plugin when you call it and use `$.extend` in the plugin's code.  You do it with `$.extend(settings, options);`, so just do the same for `messages`.

Comment: `fc` is a private variable. It's not a property of your `formCheck` function so it can't be accessed like this `formCheck.fc`.

Comment: If have seen something like I what wont to do here:

https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/localization/messages_de.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've extended jQuery's `fn` property to include your `formCheck` function. But below you're trying to access it like this

```
formCheck.fc.messages
```

Your function `formCheck` exists in a property called `fn` which lives in the jQuery object. You have to access it like this `$.fn.formCheck` or `$.fn['formCheck']`.

Second, let's say you decide to declare your function like this instead.

```
   (function () {
       var formCheck = function () {
           // Code
       }
   })();

   formCheck(); // ReferenceError. Not defined
```

Since you've wrapped it in an anonymous function, it isn't visible outside that scope. You need to expose it to the higher level of scope for the above to work.

```
   (function () {
       var formCheck = function () {
           // Code
       }

       window.formCheck = formCheck;
   })();

   formCheck(); // This works. Equivalent to calling `window.formCheck();`
```

Another thing you're doing wrong is trying to access a private variable `fc` of your function as if it were a property. 
I suggest you read this post [How to call a method inside a jquery function from global scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279486/how-to-call-a-method-inside-a-jquery-function-from-global-scope)

Comment: I have now, that I do not get access to fc. I brought the messages up one level. But it still not working. please see http://jsfiddle.net/hAfF2/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to globalize your options (make it accessible to any additional configuration by plugins). For example:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.coloredTextOptions = {
        color: 'blue'
    };
    $.fn.coloredText = function(options){
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.coloredTextOptions, options);
        return this.css('color', opts.color);
    };
})(jQuery);

$('p').coloredText(); // text is blue (as was set initially)

(function($){
    $.extend($.fn.coloredTextOptions, {
        color: 'red'
    });
})(jQuery);

$('p').coloredText(); // text is red (as modified by extend)

$('p').coloredText({ color: 'green' }); // text is green
                                        // (as overridden by passed options)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8f7La/

Comment: sorry I do not get it. I made another jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hAfF2/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/hAfF2/2/